# Cluster maintenances and automated way of re-deploying Singleton applications to apt cluster + ArgoCD

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

I am currently addressing a unique requirement and exploring potential, straightforward solutions to address this challenge.

In our current environment, we encounter scenarios where the entire Kubernetes cluster needs to be temporarily disabled for maintenance purposes. During these instances, we identify applications deployed with the Singleton annotation and create tickets for respective teams to manually relocate their applications to another preferred cluster.

Consequently, I am in the process of researching solutions that would automate the redeployment of these applications when maintenance events occur. It’s worth noting that we rely on ArgoCD for our application deployments, so any proposed solution should be compatible with ArgoCD.

While I have been looking into Open Cluster Management (OCM), it appears to be somewhat of an overkill for addressing this specific, unique use case. I am interested in learning about alternative approaches, but I find myself lacking the appropriate terminology to discover or conceptualize a potential homegrown, lightweight implementation or solution.

If anyone within the community has encountered a similar situation or can share their personal experiences, I would greatly appreciate your insights.

Best Regards!

Comment: Canary deployment should work for you. I do not see any other alterantives.